# MYSQL Error 1414 - Error doesnt make sense

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my stored procedure, which works fine on my local machine, but on PRODUCTION, it gives me the above error: Its complaining about the OUT parameter, the last one:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_projects`(
        IN userName varchar(20),
        IN projectName text,
        IN projectDescription text,
        IN projectCurrency text,
        IN projectBudget1 double,
        IN projectBudget2 double,
        IN projectEndDate DATETIME,
        IN expectedDelivDate DATETIME,
        IN projectMessageForBidder text,
        OUT projectCode bigint)
BEGIN

DECLARE 
    l_project_code bigint;

        insert into projects
        (PROJECT_CODE,
         SR_USER_NAME ,
         PROJECT_NAME,
         PROJECT_DESCRIPTION,
         PROJECT_CURRENCY,
         PROJECT_BUDGET1 ,
         PROJECT_BUDGET2 ,
         PROJECT_STATUS,
         PROJECT_END_DATE,
         PROJECT_PAID,
         EXPECTED_DELIV_DATE,
         PROJECT_MESSAGE_FOR_BIDDER,
         PROJECT_CREATION_DATE,
         PROJECT_UPDATE_DATE)
        values
        (
         0,
         userName,
         projectName,
         projectDescription,
         projectCurrency,
         projectBudget1,
         projectBudget2,
         'Active',
         projectEndDate,
         null,
         expectedDelivDate,
         projectMessageForBidder,
         NOW(),
         NOW());

         SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() into l_project_code;

         SET projectCode = l_project_code;
END
```

Below is my C# code, that sets up the parameters :

```
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("insert_projects", dbcontroller.conn);
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // Add parameters for the insert_projects STORED PROC
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("userName", SessionBag.Current.UserName));
                command.Parameters["@userName"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("projectCode", MySqlDbType.Int64));
                command.Parameters["@projectCode"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("projectName", model.projectName));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("projectDescription", model.projectDescription));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("projectCurrency", model.projectCurrency));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("projectBudget1", model.projectBudget1));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("projectBudget2", model.projectBudget2));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("projectEndDate", model.projectEndDate));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("expectedDelivDate", model.expectedDelivDate));
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("projectMessageForBidder", model.projectMessageForBidder));

                try
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    TempData["projectCode"] = (Int64)command.Parameters["?projectCode"].Value;
                    TempData["frompage"] = "AddProject";

                    dbcontroller.conn.Close();
                    return RedirectToAction("MyProjectsHeaderSR", "Projects");
                }
```

Why is is complaining about this? My local machine works fine. The table "projects" contains a field called project_code which is set to BIGINT auto-increment... The rest of the fields are normal datatypes.

Ok, I have created a variable .. and passed it in .. same error

```
            if (dbcontroller.DBConnection())
            {
                Int64 projectCode = 0;

                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("insert_projects", dbcontroller.conn);
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // Add parameters for the insert_projects STORED PROC
                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("userName", SessionBag.Current.UserName));
                command.Parameters["@userName"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

                command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("projectCode", projectCode));
                command.Parameters["@projectCode"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
```

It still doesnt work

Comment: Is your local machine running a more recent version of MySQL than the production machine? There was a related bug fixed in 5.5.3.

Comment: Yes it is ..im running 5.5.17 .. ive been trying to get the version on the production box, but these hosting providers are making me wait :-( .. I doubt they are running 5.5.17 .. Im certain as well, its the version. Can u provide me with a link to this bug fix ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/news-5-5-3.html - have a look at the section starting "Previously, prepared CALL statements..."

Answer (score 0):

The error you describe is the result of a bug in older versions of MySQL, [resolved in MySQL 5.5.3](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/news-5-5-3.html). It's probable that your local machine is running a version of MySQL where the bug has been fixed, and the production server is running an older version.

Although the best solution may be to upgrade the server, as a **workaround** until then, you could change the procedure to simply select the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (not into a variable, but into a result set), and process that result into your variable.

Incidentally, a similar situation may arise when using `INOUT` parameters. Although you are using an `OUT` parameter (and so the following does not apply in your case), the situation would arise when an `INOUT` parameter but not providing a variable to populate, the following would similarly apply.

The line:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("projectCode", MySqlDbType.Int64));
```

...is providing a named parameter to the command object, and a type, but not giving it anything to populate. If you were using an `INOUT` parameter, you would need to provide a empty variable and pass it in; it'll give the SP something to output to.

Comment: projectCode is the return value from the stored procedure. I have used this method above throughout my code, in returning values from the DB. If i want to return a field, called projectType, which is called project_type in the DB, i will do the same as above and it works. The only difference in the above code, is projectCode is an auto-increment and i do a SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() into l_project_code. In yur explanation above, how do i do what u suggest? can u give me an example?

Comment: Ok, they are using MYSQL version 5.0.77 .. It looks like when im declaring MYSQL parameters within my C# code, the order in which i declare them MATTERS based on the order in which these parameters are being received in the Stored Procedure. However, on MY side, version 5.5.17, i declare these parameters in any order, and it still works .. Is it the version, or is MY coding incorrect ? Does the order actually matter ?

Comment: The [docs for 5.3.3](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/call.html) say this: "For programs written in a language that provides a MySQL interface, there is no native method prior to MySQL 5.5.3 for directly retrieving the results of OUT or INOUT parameters from CALL statements. To get the parameter values, pass user-defined variables to the procedure in the CALL statement and then execute a SELECT statement to produce a result set containing the variable values". I guess the placeholder location is relevant.